# Redeclared variable unused

Tags: go

This code compiles:

```
func (wc *WordCounter) Write(buf []byte) (int, error) {
    for adv, i := 0, 0; i < len(buf); i += adv {
        adv, _, _ = bufio.ScanWords(buf[i:], true)
        *wc++
    }
    return len(buf), nil
}
```

But the following does not compile. Notice the short declaration `adv, token, _ := ..` where I expected that `adv` would be *redeclared* (as opposed to be declared as a new var):

```
func (wc *WordCounter) Write(buf []byte) (int, error) {
    for adv, i := 0, 0; i < len(buf); i += adv {
        // error: adv declared and not used
        adv, token, _ := bufio.ScanWords(buf[i:], true) 
        fmt.Println(string(token))
        *wc++
    }
    return len(buf), nil
}
```

According to the Go spec:

> a short variable declaration may redeclare variables provided they
>   were originally declared earlier in the same block. [...] *Redeclaration* does not introduce a new variable; it just assigns a new value to the original.

I guess this means that the `for` statement is a block in and of itself, and that `adv` therefore is considered to be declared over again (as opposed to being *redeclared*) in the `for` body?

Comment: I don't think your conclusion follows, if the for statement was a 'block in and of itself' the first example should complain that adv is not declared.

Comment: As far as I understand [point number 4.](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blocks) confirms your conclusion.

Comment: Andrew, that's not the case.  The interior of the for loop would still be a nested block, and thus would be able to use the adv as declared in the parent scope (the for loop), which is the case here.  Variables declared within the loop syntax itself are considered to be a different scope than those declared inside the loop, because those declared inside the loop are local to only that _iteration_ of the loop, while variables declared in the for loop itself are local to _all_ iterations.

Comment: The point I am trying to make is that the short variable declaration `:=` may or may not redeclare a variable, depending on in which scope it was previously declared. And in this particular case it was a bit surprising to see that the compiler did not choose to redeclare it, but rather to introduce it as a new variable within the `for` body.

Comment: Quite so, and the fact that the short-form declaration statement cannot be fully human-parsed for meaning without examining surrounding code is one of my grievances with Go.  It definitely feels like it violates the whole Go-code-is-easy-to-read convention.

Answer (score 4):

This is working as intended.  Consider the following:

https://play.golang.org/p/cyJZgM5QYn

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%p", &i)
        i := i
        fmt.Printf(" | %p\n", &i)
    }
}
```

Variables you declare within the `for` loop header are defined for the entire for loop.  The first `i` printed in the above has the same address on every single iteration.  On the other hand, variables declared inside the loop itself are local *only to that iteration of the loop!*  Note that the second `i` printed on each line has a unique address, as a new variable is being created on each iteration.  This makes the lifetime of the two variables, and thus their scopes, different.  Since they exist in separate scopes, the inner scope can (usually inadvertently) shadow the outer scope variable via the short-form declaration.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess this means that the for statement is a block in and of itself,
> and that adv therefore is considered to be declared over again (as
> opposed to being redeclared) in the for body?

Yes, that's correct. Go specs say following about blocks:

> A block is a possibly empty sequence of declarations and statements
> within matching brace brackets.
>
> Each "if", "for", and "switch" statement is considered to be in its own implicit block.

So you are declaring a new variable in your for-block with the same name as the previously declared variable. The new variable shadows the previously declared variable making it inaccessible from inside the for-block.

This is a common source of bugs if you don't realize there are now two variables with the same name and you think you are assigning values to the variable you declared in the outer block. `go vet` with the `-shadow=true` option can help find such bugs.